# Requesting Django server using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

my views.py -

```
def wall(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        if 'logout' in post:
            del request.session['username']
            return redirect('home')
        elif 'post' in post:
            if post['post_text'] and not post['post_text'].isspace():
                posted_by = request.session.get('username', '')
                post_content = post['post_text']
                post_id = posted_by+''+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p on %B %d, %Y")
                p = user_post(posted_by = posted_by, post_content = post_content, post_id = post_id)
                p.save()
                return redirect('wall')
            else:
                return redirect('error')
        elif 'search_user' in post:
            return redirect('search_user')
        elif 'profile' in post:
            return redirect('profile') 
    else:
        if 'username' in request.session:
            posts = user_post.objects.order_by('id')[:20].reverse()
            return render(request, 'wall/wall_page.html', {'posts': posts, 'user': request.session['username']}) 
        else:
            return redirect('error')
```

template -

```
<div class="row" id="posts">
            {% if posts %}
                {% for post in posts %}
                    {% if user == post.posted_by %}
                        <p class="lead text-success text-right">
                            {{ post.post_content }}
                            <small>
                                <small>
                                    <small>
                                        <small>
                                            {{ post.posted_by }}
                                        </small>
                                    </small>
                                </small>
                            </small>
                        </p>
                    {% else %}
                        <p class="lead text-info text-left">
                            {{ post.post_content }}
                            <small>
                                <small>
                                    <small>
                                        <small>
                                            {{ post.posted_by }}
                                        </small>
                                    </small>
                                </small>
                            </small>
                        </p>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
```

and related js file -

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        setInterval(function() 
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type : "GET",
                url : "http://10.8.21.17:8000/wall/wall",
            }).done(function()
            {
                $('#posts').html();
            });
        }, 3000);
    });
```

There is proper GET request to the server but the page is not reloading...i.e. when a user post something it is actually not showing to other users even if there is a GET request every 3 second. I copy-pasted the js code and dont know if it is correct. Anyone help me please. What i want to do is that the page should reload with the help of js so that user dont have to refresh.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the response from the server in your JS. You need to actually use it:

```
.done(function(data)
        {
            $('#posts').html(data);
        });
```